# Composer PSR-4 autoloading completely ignored

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I have composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "marko/art-empire",
    "description": "Social network",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Marko Ilic",
            "email": "markowebdeveloper@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Songs\\": "songs/"
      }
    }
}
```

---

autoload_psr4.php file:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Songs\\' => array($baseDir . '/songs'),
);
```

---

RandomSong.php file in songs folder (which is in root directory):

```
namespace Song;

class RandomSong
{
    public function songName()
    {
        return 'Random Song';
    }
}
```

---

test.php file:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Songs\RandomSong;

$randomSong = new RandomSong();
echo $randomSong->songName();
```

---

As you can see I am trying to autoload RandomSong class, but I keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Songs\RandomSong' not found in test.php
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace is called `Song`, but you refer to it as `Songs`

Comment: Wow, how didn't i see that?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `RandomSong` uses `Song` namespace, while your loader is for `Songs` namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this solves your problem, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).